# IDE for Android

Tags: android, ide

I used to lug my huge laptop all over the place, but now I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1. Im loving the lighter baggage and I can do everything I can do on my laptop, expect for the most important thing, develop. The main reason for this is because i cant find a decent ide that runs on Android, so I'm putting the question out there. Is there and ide i can run on the Android platform?

Comment: What language do you want to develop in?

Comment: As many languages as popular. Mainly php, java an if possible C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly on android? No I don't think so.

However it is possible to install ubuntu on a tablet.  Then you could use eclipse or any other linux IDE, I suppose.  Heres a video showing you how to install ubuntu on a tablet.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agYEOefFfto

UPDATE

[Terminal IDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) allows for full java/android development on your android device (no root required). I believe C and C++ support is in the works as well.  Project is open source and includes the following executable's:

javac, java, dx, proguard, aapt, apkbuilder, signer, ssh, sshd, telnetd, bash 4.2, busybox 1.19.2, vim 7.3, nano 2.2.6, midnight commander 4.8, htop 1.0, TMUX 1.5, rsync 3.0.8, git 1.7.8, BitchX 1.1.

You'll definitely need a bluetooth keyboard to get any real productivity out of it, but its a great app.

Answer (score 5):

[AIDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aide.ui) supports the full edit-compile-run cycle for Android Apps and has a great editor. It works fine on my devices (Transformer Prime and Samsung Galaxy S2).